# Using the default value defined in model in a query in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Im using Rails 5. I have a Product model defined as follows

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :image_url, presence: true

  def image_url
    super || 'http://someplaceholderimage.com'
  end
end
```

Every product has an image_url attribute. Now, when i run the below query:

```
Product.all.where.not(image_url: nil)
```

im expecting it to return all products even if the image_url was nil in the database for any of them. But the default value i defined in the model is not being used and im getting only those products whose image_url column has a non nil value in the database. How can i fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's an instance method. It'll work on any instance of the Product class.

Every single query made to your database through the models is a class method. So they're not going to work as you expected.

What you can do is to add a default value to that column in your database. So, whenever a record is inserted, with nil (NULL) image_url, it'll take the value you defined as default.

---

It also exists the possibility to add a default value using the SQL `CASE` expression, which adds more flexibility regarding the need you have:

```
Product.select("CASE WHEN image_url IS NULL
                THEN 'http://someplaceholderimage.com'
                ELSE image_url END, *")
```

(this is PostgreSQL syntax)

Combining both ways you won't have to add more code to your model.

For changing the default value of the column, you can use `change_column_default`:

```
class ChangeImageUrlDefaultProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column_default :products, :image_url, from: nil, to: 'http://someplaceholderimage.com'
  end
end
```

This is reversible by using the `from` and `to` option arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this approach will work only for new records that i create. Any past records that have a nil value wont get the default value. Is there a way i can make it work for past records having a nil value for image_url as well ?

Comment: You can update all of them with a single query. `Product.where(image_url: nil).update_all(image_url: 'http://someplaceholderimage.com')`. Regarding to your question; it depends what you're querying the database for, I can see you're trying to get all Products whether the image_url is nil or not, for that Product.all would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails `.where()` is structuring some SQL to be called on the database. So the code is doing what you asked: it's going to the database and asking for all records where image_url is not nil.

What you are defining on the model is a method that:

1. looks for an image_url in the database
2. returns it if there is one
3. returns 'http://someplaceholderimage.com' if there isn't one

To achieve your stated goal:

> im expecting it to return all products even if the image_url was nil in the database

You simply need to call `Product.all`

I'm not sure why you would add `.where.not()` if you didn't want that to be a condition.

To really drive the point home: Expecting the database to return records where `:image_url` is either nil or not nil:

`Product.where(image_url: nil).or(Product.where.not(image_url: nil))` is the same as calling `Product.all`

---

If you want to make sure every record has a URL defined in the database, you could do a `before_validation` callback in the Model:

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :image_url, presence: true

  before_save :default_image_url, if: ->{ image_url.blank? }

  # def image_url
  #   super || 'http://someplaceholderimage.com'
  # end

  private

  def default_image_url
    image_url ||= 'http://someplaceholderimage.com'
  end
end
```

---

If you want to be able to tell which records are returning the default `:image_url` and which records have an `:image_url` saved in the database, you need to rename the method so it doesn't conflict with the database column name:

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :image_url, presence: true

  def image
    image_url || 'http://someplaceholderimage.com'
  end
end
```

Now calling `@product.image_url` will return whatever is in the database and calling `@product.image` will either return the dB value or the placeholder value.

---

**But, there's another issue:**
Your `validates :image_url, presence: true` means the record will never save if the `:image_url` is blank.

So asking the database to look for a potentially nil value when you've already ensured that every record can't have a nil value is a bit of a head-scratcher.

---

Final tangent: 
If you must have the method name and database column name match, I don't think `super` is a good option.

I think you should use this:

```rb
def image_url
  read_attribute(:image_url) || 'http://someplaceholderimage.com'
end
```

If nothing else, it's a bit more clear than `super` as to what is happening.